# How to load the content of a tab delimited file into a 2D vector of strings in C++ when data contains spaces?

Tags: c++, string, text-files, stdvector

I have the following code to load the content of a tab separated file into a 2D vector of strings. Problem is that this is code fails if there is any space in the data. How can I modify the code to take that into account.

```
const std::size_t columns = 4;
std::string word;
std::size_t count = 0;
std::ifstream in("some_file");
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
std::vector<std::string> row;
while(in >> word) {
    row.push_back(std::move(word));
    if(++count % columns == 0) {
        data.push_back(std::move(row));
        row.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use std::getline to get the entire line, then split the line into separate strings based on a tab delimiter. Something like this:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string line;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;

while(std::getline(in, line)) {
    std::string phrase;
    std::vector<std::string> row;
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while(std::getline(ss, phrase, '\t')) {
        row.push_back(std::move(phrase));
    }
    data.push_back(std::move(row));
}
```